# how to Create CListBox in CDockablePane and fill the whole size?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc, ribbon

I Create a class which it derive from CDockablePane,the code like this.

```
class CWorkspaceBar : public CDockablePane
{
public:
    CWorkspaceBar();

// Attributes
protected:

    CXListBox   m_wndThumbList;

// Operations
public:

// Overrides

// Implementation
public:
    virtual ~CWorkspaceBar();

protected:
    afx_msg int OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct);
    afx_msg void OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy);
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

In function CWorkspaceBar::OnCreate I Create a CListBox.

```
int CWorkspaceBar::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct) 
{
    if (CDockablePane::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    CRect rectDummy;
    rectDummy.SetRectEmpty();
    if (!m_wndThumbList.Create (WS_CHILDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE |WS_VSCROLL|WS_HSCROLL| LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED|LBS_HASSTRINGS|LBS_NOTIFY,rectDummy, this,IDC_THUMBNAILIMAGELIST))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create workspace view\n");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And in function CWorkspaceBar::OnSize I resize the CListBox Object,But it Can't fill the whole Parent Window.

```
void CWorkspaceBar::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy) 
{
    CDockablePane::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);
    if(IsWindow(m_wndThumbList.GetSafeHwnd()))
        m_wndThumbList.SetWindowPos (NULL,0,0,cx,cy, SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOZORDER);
}
```

I tested CListCtrl And CTreeCtrl,It's Works well,Only the CListBox can't fill the whole of Parent Window. How to fix it,Is this a bug of MFC ?

[image: bug]
<sub>(source: [image-share.com](https://www.image-share.com/upload/2277/168.png))</sub>

Comment: Make sure you set the `LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT` style when you create your `CListBox` - by default, it will limit itself on size to fit an integral number of items.

Comment: @RogerRowland your answer is ok,thanks!  but what's function of this Integral Height ?

Answer (score 2):

Use LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT when you create the list box.